# Know where is assigned Azure IP

Tags: azure

I have a lot of services and apps deployed on Azure and I want to Know where an specific IP is assigned

I have searched on internet but i dont find any solution

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this info in the portal.  Search for Public IP address and click on the "edit columns".  This will allow you to add the IP address column.  Once you find the IP address you are looking for, click on it and look at the "association" field.

[image]